# Convert \n in list using Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I am trying to convert a string to sLineBreak in a list to use , but the following code gives me error:

```
var
   SLista: TStringList;
   Arrangement: array of String;
   Index: Integer;
   text: string;

     SLista: = TStringList.Create;
     Text: = 'hi' + sLineBreak + 'world' + sLineBreak + 'yeah' + sLineBreak
       + 'Yeah';

     SLista.Delimiter: = sLineBreak;
     SLista.DelimitedText: = text;

     SetLength (Arrangement SLista.Count);
     for index: = 0 to Pred (SLista.Count) do
       Writeln (SLista [index]);
```

The error :

[DCC Error] test.dpr(120): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'AnsiString'

As I can accomplish this?

Comment: It really helps if you don't post fake code. The code you posted has multiple other errors. Please post the code that you actually use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sLineBreak const is defined as the string #13#10. TStringList.Delimiter is a char and therefore you can't assign sLineBreak to it. Instead of assigning to SLista.DelimitedText use

```
SLista.Text := text;
```

If you specifically want to use DelimitedText you can use either #13 or #10 as Delimiter to split your text in lines. But note that the Text property always uses sLineBreak for line breaks, even if you assigned the content via DelimitedText with #13 or #10 as Delimiter.

As a side note, if you use the Delimiter and DelimitedText properties, make sure you consider the effects of space characters in the text vs. StrictDelimiter property as well as quote characters in the text vs. QuoteChar property.

Comment: Certainly on Windows sLineBreak is `#13#10`

Answer (score 2):

The code is needlessly complex because assigning to `Text` results in the input string being split on line breaks. So you can replace your code with this:

```
SLista := TStringList.Create;
try
  SLista.Text: = 'hi' + sLineBreak + 'world' + sLineBreak + 'yeah' + sLineBreak
    + 'Yeah';
  for str in SLista do
    Writeln(str);
finally
  SList.Free;
end;
```